# Display Author Registration Date

Tags: date

In author archive, I want to show author registration date in the following format:

> January 16, 2021

I have found this code:

```
$user_ID = $post->post_author;
echo the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $user_ID );
```

But its output format is:

> 2021-01-16 10:40:52

How can I strip off time and get my desired format?

I am using date format `F j, Y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about reformat it instead of stripping?

```
//Get post author ID
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post->ID );

//Get the registration date
$registered_date = get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $post_author_id );

//Convert to desired format
$output = date( 'F j, Y', strtotime($registered_date));

//Echo
echo $output;
```

Comment: Your code is outputing this: `2021-01-16 10:40:52January 1, 1970`
Have you checked the code?

Comment: It shouldn't. Check if you already has your previous code enabled and is outputting the numeric date, i.e  `12021-01-16 10:40:52`.

Comment: Anyway, just fixed a typo. Check now.

Comment: it works! Thank you very much.